# Java Functions as Objects

Tags: java, function, jvm

I have a very good use for having functions as objects in Java, aka the following sort of thing:

```
Function handle_packet_01 = void handle() {}
```

I don't want to use Scala because I can't stand the syntax.

Is there any sort of hack that I can apply to the JVM to allow me to do this? How about an Eclipse plugin?

I saw a similar sort of thing for operator overloading in Java, which I am going to install the plugin for too.

Comment: Please read about java 8 api 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html#overview

Additionally, You can simulate such approach with creating interface with syntax of handle method.

Comment: Thanks, I will go and read up about it now. Since this is just for a server, Java 8 is good.

Comment: @GergelyBacso, there's an Eclipse plugin that lets you use operator overloading in your Java code, so anything's possible, right?

Comment: Thanks to those who suggested lambdas, they're perfect for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 8 you can reference a member method as following

```
MyClass::function
```

**EDIT:** A more complete example

```
//For this example I am creating an interface that will serve as predicate on my method
public interface IFilter
{
   int[] apply(int[] data);
}

//Methods that follow the same rule for return type and parameter type from IFilter may be referenced as IFilter
public class FilterCollection
{
    public static int[] median(int[]) {...}
    public int[] mean(int[]) {...}
    public void test() {...}
}

//The class that we are working on and has the method that uses an IFilter-like method as reference
public class Sample
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       FilterCollection f = new FilterCollection();
       int[] data = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

      //Static method reference or object method reference
      data = filterByMethod(data, FilterCollection::median);
      data = filterByMethod(data, f::mean);

      //This one won't work as IFilter type
      //data = filterByMethod(data, f::test); 
   }

   public static int[] filterByMethod(int[] data, IFilter filter)
   {
       return filter.apply(data);
   }

}
```

Also take a look at [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for another example and usage of method reference

Comment: Quick question, what is the type of FIlter::median?

Comment: @Lolums I have now provided a better and more complete example.